# Unable to play Video or Audio

Tags: sound, video, plugins

I am unable to play Video or Audio on ubuntu 13.10

[image: this is the response i am seeing]

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is long dead!

Comment: Oh... I want to change from Windows to ubuntu...

Comment: Which Linux would you suggest to me?

Comment: Supported versions now are 18.04 LTS(long term support) and 19.10.  19.10 will need to be upgraded to 20.04 after June.  When installing should click box to install restricted extras.